# Can't isolate pixels from av_frame_copy_to_buffer

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to pull the YUV pixel data from an AVFrame, modify the pixels,  and put it back into FFmpeg.

I'm currently using this to retrieve the YUV buffer

```
const AVPixFmtDescriptor *desc = av_pix_fmt_desc_get(base->format);
int baseSize = av_image_get_buffer_size(base->format, base->width, base->height, 32);
uint8_t *baseBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(baseSize);
av_image_copy_to_buffer(baseBuffer, baseSize, base->data, base->linesize, base->format, base->width, base->height, 32);
```

But I can't seem to correctly target pixels in that buffer. From the source code they seem to be stacking the planes on top of each other, leading me to attempt this

```
int width = base->width;
int height = base->height;
int chroma2h = desc->log2_chroma_h;
int linesizeY = base->linesize[0];
int linesizeU = base->linesize[1];
int linesizeV = base->linesize[2];
int chromaHeight = (height + (1 << chroma2h) -1) >> chroma2h;

int x = 100;
int y = 100;

uint8_t *vY = base;
uint8_t *vU = base +(linesizeY*height);
uint8_t *vV = base +((linesizeY*height) + (linesizeU*chromaHeight));
vY+= x + (y * linesizeY);
vU+= x + (y * linesizeU);
vV+= x + (y * linesizeV);
```

Using that, if I try to modify pixels from a range of `300,300-400,400` I get a small box darker than the rest of the video, along with horizontal stripes of darkness along the video. The original color is still there, so I think I'm still touching the Y plane on all 3 pointers.

How can I actually hit the pixels I want to hit?

Comment: What is the gop-size with which the video was encoded?

Comment: @SamerTufail I counted 249 P frames between the I ones.

Comment: can you try setting a gop-size of 1 and trying the above

Comment: @SamerTufail Nope, same result. I should note that the copy_buffer command is called inside a vf_filter, and the buffer is passed to an external file that modifies the pixels.

Comment: once you have a gop size of 1 just try modifying the AVFrame->data[0] - obviously a deep copy of it(as above) and not the original

Comment: @SamerTufail so now I'm able to set a region green, but I still see artifacts from the original video in the block.

Comment: could you paste some code or detail how you have gone about that?